# Two-dimensional data type assigned to vector

Tags: r, vector, multidimensional-array, r-sf

How to use R convert the 'source index' into a vector data column which is :index(a vector value),START_X START_Y

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
list.files("ljz_network.gdb")
ljz<-readOGR("ljz_network.gdb",use_iconv = TRUE)
ogrInfo(dsn = "ljz_network.gdb",encoding = NULL,use_iconv = FALSE,require_geomType = NULL,
        morphFromESRI = NULL, dumpSRS = FALSE, enforce_xy = NULL)
print(ljz)
```

> geometry | START_X | START_Y | Shape_Length |
> MULTILINESTRING((13530030 3636987 ...)) | 13530033 | 3636987 | 44.304098
> ...

```
ID<-1:nrow(network)
df<-data.frame(ID,c(ljz))
```

> back:
> |  |  | START_X |
> START_Y |
> Shape_Length |
> ID |
> 1 |
> 13530033 |
> 3636987 |
> 44.304098 |
> 1 |
> 2 |
> 13530033 |
> 3636987 |
> 30.773139 |
> 2 |

```
sp_df<-st_sfc(df(list(cbind(c(ID),c(network)))))
```

> Error in df(list(cbind(c(ID), c(network)))) :
> argument "df1" is missing, with no default

I can't convert the ID column into a vector type...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Based on your error messages, there seems to be missing values in your data. Before using `percolate()`, check your data to make sure there are no missing values and that the data is in the right format.

Comment: Thanks your advice...the data need to pull in an unique index value which from the source database..I don't know how to pull in  the source database into R

Comment: From what you provided, `ljz` is a spatial dataframe with 9 columns and 2795 rows. The values you want are probably in those columns, which work like other columns in other dataframes. Type `ljz` in the R console and it should show you the structure. There are free resources that might be helpful to learn about geocomputation in R, e.g.: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/index.html

Comment: Thanks your advice...I try to make the source and the other two colums into a dataframe,but I can't convert the 'source index' into a vector data column